# Scripts disappearing from package when deploying

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

Recently I tried to deploy SSIS packages on our production environment and after struggling with some errors I checked contents of packages by importing them from server(not from deployment file) into SSDT. What I found was really interesting - C# code from Script Task(we got only one script task) was gone, there was only template code even with comments that you see when you add Script Task to your package, it looked like it wasn't ever edited by anyone.

I asked my colleague if he could deploy same project on same server instead of me, and it worked, code was on it's place and everything went smooth from there.

What may have caused this behavior? We both are server admins, we both have sysadmin permissions on SQL Server and we don't know about any permissions that he has and I don't.

EDIT: We were both deploying same .ispac project deployment file, none of us edited it after it was "production ready". We also deploy it in the same way - double click on .ispac file, and using Integration Services Deployment Wizard.
Packages are prepared on different server.

Comment: Packages should never be modified by the deployment process.  I never heard of such a thing as a script task losing it's script before.  Could you describe the method you are using and to where you are deploying the project?  Also, could you please confirm you and your colleague are deploying from the same source code?  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a very similar problem.  A previous post existed which may have been subsequently removed, but I can attest that the process script task in the SSIS packages are being replaced with an empty or default Task.  I suspect an incompatibility in versions or a dll found in the  SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn directories.

We currently developed using Visual Studio 2013 Professional with SSDT integrated into it (did not use the shell or standalone version).  Development took place on a Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit machine with SP1.  All testing was fine locally using SSDT.  When deployed to the server, testing worked as intended.  The server is where I believe the problem is originating.  We deployed to a SQL Server Enterprise Edition running on Windows Server 2012 R2.  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-GDR) (KB3194720) - 12.0.4232.0 (X64).  The ispac was generated from an export in SSMS in the SQL Server Integration Services Catalog.  The ispac was then deployed to another site.

Turns out the site had deployed this to a SQL Server Developer 64 Bit instance.  Theoretically, this should work, but when importing the deployed project back into a Visual Studio SSDT standalone instance (not embedded in Visual Studio Professional) at this site, all the Process Script Tasks were replaced with the default instance of a Process Task.
When reproducing the scenario in-house, on a SQL Server 2014 Developer 64 Bit as the deployment site, and then importing it back into a new Visual Studio SSDT project, the Process Scripts are indeed replaced.  When creating a new Visual Studio SSDT project and importing them from the Enterprise Edition, the Process Scripts are all there.

For us, it seems to be a strong correlation between the SQL Server versions, or the fact of them being different.